# Can't use enter key shortcut on Google search results anymore

Tags: google-search

Up until last week, Google used to place a blue arrow on the first search result. Using the arrow keys, one could select different results. Finally, pressing enter would enter into the selected result. For the past few days, these keyboard shortcuts are no longer there. How do I re-enable them? I search on Google every 10 minutes and can't afford to waste 2 seconds each time pointing my mouse at the desired link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible anymore. It used to be possible with Tab and the arrow keys, but Google removed that feature.

You can use a browser extension like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-keyboard-sh/iobmefdldoplhmonnnkchglfdeepnfhd?hl=en) to enable this feature again.

Comment: This works. It's strange why they removed it. They should have kept it there to promote more usage of keyboard shortcuts. Using the mouse is a huge time kill.

Comment: So there's another problem. If I'm logged in to my Google account, hitting enter will do a Google +1 on that link rather than go to the link.

Comment: Check your tab order. If that's the case, *just* press Enter after you entered your search term and the arrow will appear.

Comment: @Flimm Fixed it